# install latest version of realm using cocoapods in terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal, cocoapods, realm

how to install latest version of realm in the terminal using cocoapods.

ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.4. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.4` and then running the current command again
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.3.62.
[!] `Realm` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.9.3`.

I Tried this but not working!

1
Update the CocoaPods repositories
On the command line, run pod repo update to ensure CocoaPods can access the latest available Realm versions.

2
Initialize CocoaPods for Your Project
If you do not already have a Podfile for your project, run pod init in the root directory of your project to create a Podfile for your project. A Podfile allows you to specify project dependencies to CocoaPods.

3
Add Realm as a Dependency in Your Podfile

Swift

Objective C
Add the line use_frameworks! if it is not already there.

Add the line pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10' to your main and test targets.

When done, your Podfile should look something like this:

platform :ios, '12.0'
target 'MyRealmProject' do

## Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!

## Pods for MyRealmProject

pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10'
end

4
Install the Dependencies
From the command line, run pod install to fetch the dependencies.

5
Use the CocoaPods-Generated .xcworkspace File
CocoaPods generates an .xcworkspace file for you. This file has all of the dependencies configured. From now on, open this file -- not the .xcodeproj file -- to work on your project.

Comment: It seems the question is about activesupport? We need some clarity in the question so including your actual podFile, OS Version, XCode version and CocoaPods version (pod --version) is needed. Providing instructions for using Cocoapods isn't relevant to the question so that could be removed.